# I can not configure the environment variables with docker

Tags: php, docker, docker-compose, environment-variables

I am using docker in my php application, everything works fine, but the problem is that it can not read the environment variables.

when my application is uploaded to the git repository, the .env is ignored and an .env.example or .env.dist is uploaded, when cloning the project and doing the application build with docker-compose up, it does not work since there is no .env

I tried to make a cp .env.example .env
to generate it, but it still does not work.
this is my docker-compose file:

```
version: "3.1"
services:

    webserver:
      image: nginx:alpine
      container_name: x-webserver
      working_dir: /app
      volumes:
         - .:/app
         - ./phpdocker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
  command: mv .env.example .env
  environment:
    - "DB_HOST=host"
    - "DB_PORT=3306"
    - "DATABASE=x"
    - "DB_USER=admin"
    - "DB_PASSWORD="
  ports:
    - "8000:80"

php-fpm:
  build: phpdocker/php-fpm
  container_name: x-php-fpm
  working_dir: /app
  volumes:
    - .:/app
    - ./phpdocker/php-fpm/php-ini overrides.ini:/etc/php/7.3/fpm/conf.d/99-overrides.ini
composer:
  restart: 'no'
  image: "composer"
  command: install
  volumes:
    - .:/app
```

What do I need to do so that the .env file can be used by docker?

Comment: you already have ENV vars in your docker-compose. The one in your .env file are diff?

Comment: Is the .env file configurations for your php application rather than your database? I know laravel takes this approach. If that's the case, I'll also need to know where the .env file is in relation to your docker-compose. Rather then using a command to move it, we could just make it available via the volume to the container.

Comment: the .env.example is in the root folder, also the docker-compose file, both are in the same root directory.